# org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: NULL not allowed for column "ID"; SQL statement problem with @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) id

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I'm getting this problem when I try to save an object in the DB.

> org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: NULL not allowed for column "ID"; SQL
>   statement: insert into Credential (id, fisicHost_id, notes, password,
>   role, user) values (null, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) [23502-191]  at
>   org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.done(SessionRemote.java:624)
>   ~[h2-1.4.191.jar:1.4.191]     at
>   org.h2.command.CommandRemote.executeUpdate(CommandRemote.java:191)
>   ~[h2-1.4.191.jar:1.4.191]     at
>   org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:160)
>   ~[h2-1.4.191.jar:1.4.191]     at
>   org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:146)
>   ~[h2-1.4.191.jar:1.4.191]     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:97)
>   ~[tomcat-dbcp-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]  at
>   org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:97)
>   ~[tomcat-dbcp-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]  at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:204)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.6.Final.jar:5.0.6.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(IdentityGenerator.java:84)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.6.Final.jar:5.0.6.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:42)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.6.Final.jar:5.0.6.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2792)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.6.Final.jar:5.0.6.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3362)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.6.Final.jar:5.0.6.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:81)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.6.Final.jar:5.0.6.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:597)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.6.Final.jar:5.0.6.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:232)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.6.Final.jar:5.0.6.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:213)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.6.Final.jar:5.0.6.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:256)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.6.Final.jar:5.0.6.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:317)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.6.Final.jar:5.0.6.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:272)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.6.Final.jar:5.0.6.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:178)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.6.Final.jar:5.0.6.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:109)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.6.Final.jar:5.0.6.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:192)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.6.Final.jar:5.0.6.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:38)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.6.Final.jar:5.0.6.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:177)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.6.Final.jar:5.0.6.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:32)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.6.Final.jar:5.0.6.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:73)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.6.Final.jar:5.0.6.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:679)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.6.Final.jar:5.0.6.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:671)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.6.Final.jar:5.0.6.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:666)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.6.Final.jar:5.0.6.Final]     at
>   com.amco.Datacenter.dao.CredentialDaoImpl.save(CredentialDaoImpl.java:55)
>   ~[main/:na]   at
>   com.amco.Datacenter.dao.CredentialDaoImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$67cc97d9.invoke()
>   ~[main/:na]   at
>   org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
>   ~[spring-core-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:721)
>   ~[spring-aop-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
>   ~[spring-aop-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
>   ~[spring-tx-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>   ~[spring-aop-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:656)
>   ~[spring-aop-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]     at
>   com.amco.Datacenter.dao.CredentialDaoImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c7ae50e6.save()
>   ~[main/:na]   at
>   com.amco.Datacenter.service.CredentialServiceImpl.save(CredentialServiceImpl.java:34)
>   ~[main/:na]   at
>   com.amco.Datacenter.controller.Controlador.addCredential(Controlador.java:45)
>   ~[main/:na]   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_121]   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_121]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_121]   at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:220)
>   ~[spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:134)
>   ~[spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:116)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]  at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]  at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]  at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]  at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
>   ~[spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   ~[spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]  at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:89)
>   ~[spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   ~[spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]  at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
>   ~[spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   ~[spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]  at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
>   ~[spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   ~[spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]   at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]   at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]   at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]   at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:784)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]   at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]   at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:802)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]   at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1410)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]   at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>   [na:1.8.0_121]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>   [na:1.8.0_121]    at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]   at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_121]

This is the Credential class with the autogenerated ID (can't guess why it's null)

```
@Entity
public class Credential {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne(fetch= FetchType.LAZY)
    private FisicHost fisicHost;

    private String user;
    private String password;
    private String notes;
    private String role;

    public Credential(){

    }

    public Credential(int id, FisicHost fisicHost, String user, String password, String notes, String role) {
        this.id = id;
        this.fisicHost = fisicHost;
        this.user = user;
        this.password = password;
        this.notes = notes;
        this.role = role;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public FisicHost getFisicHost() {
        return fisicHost;
    }

    public void setFisicHost(FisicHost fisicHost) {
        this.fisicHost = fisicHost;
    }

    public String getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(String user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getNotes() {
        return notes;
    }

    public void setNotes(String notes) {
        this.notes = notes;
    }

    public String getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    public void setRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }
}
```

and this is the controller method that handles the request:

```
// Método para agregar credenciales
@RequestMapping(value = "/fisicHost/{id}/credentials/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void addCredential(@PathVariable(value = "id") int fisicHostId, @RequestParam(value = "User") String user,
                          @RequestParam(value = "Password") String password, @RequestParam(value = "Notes") String notes){
    FisicHost fisicHost = fisicHostDao.findById(fisicHostId);
    List<Credential> allCredentials = fisicHost.getCredentials();
    Credential credential = new Credential();
    credential.setUser(user);
    credential.setPassword(password);
    credential.setNotes(notes);
    credentialService.save(credential);
}
```

This is how the CredentialDaoImpl.java save method is coded:

```
@Override
public void save(Credential credential) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    session.save(credential);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();
}
```

I debugged the program and the values are the expected ones, the problem is that the Credential is not saving properly due to this null id problem which I can't guess why is happenning.

Any idea ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to set H2 primary key id to auto_increment?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11299675/5221149)

Comment: What database are you using?  How is the id column generated?  Something like this? `ID int not null generated always as identity (start with 1, increment by 1, no cache)`

Comment: I'm using H2 and Hibernate ... the ID column is autogenerated in the Credential.java class with the `@Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)` annotations

Comment: Your code look normal. Add at the application.properties two lines: spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update. Restart application. Your tables recreates. And you can find DDL for your tables in log-file. Find Credential table and check that id is a "id integer generated by default as identity". If it is true - try again to save Credential.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I restarted everything and worked fine .... can't tell what the problem was

Comment: @Nacho Zve De La Torre I think that your tables was not recreated after some changes and  `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)` conflicted with old table-schema.